# Why does the lower bound on the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function make it non-integrable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

We have that $$Hf(x) \geq \frac{c}{|x|^n}$$ for some $c>0$ whenever $|x| \geq 1$. How does this lower bound show that that the maximal function is non-integrable? Perhaps if we could show that $\frac{c}{|x|^n}$ isn't integrable outside the unit ball we could show this. However, I am not sure how to do this. Similar questions seem to imply that it is obvious given the inequality.

Comment: Use polar coordinates.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use polar coordinates in $R^n$. Is there a way to do it without polar coordinates?

Comment: Rudin's RCA tells you how to use polar coordinates in $\mathbb R^{n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Observe
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{dx}{|x|^n} =\int^\infty_0 \int_{|x|=r} \frac{1}{|x|^n}\ dS(x)dr
\end{align}